# HTML generated by extension not showing up when attempting to parse

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer, cheerio

I am working on a project which would log the floats of certain weapon skins on a steam marketplace page. For a little bit of background, the float values associated with each listing only show up when the CSGOFloat chrome extension is used. I am using puppeteer and have managed to have it open the correct page with the extension enabled; however, when I attempt to parse through the HTML using cheerio to find the float value, it doesn't show up. Even when I just print all the HTML to the screen it doesn't show up. When I inspect the browser that puppeteer opened, the HTML relating to the float is there. Can someone explain why I can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about puppeteer more. You don't need to use Cheerio load for element.

```
await page.$eval('#breadcrumbs > ol > li:nth-child(2)', el => el.innerText);

await page.waitForSelector("[name='login[username]");
await page.type("[name='login[username]']", "userid);
await page.waitForSelector("[name='login[password]");
await page.type("[name='login[password]']", "password");

await page.keyboard.down('Control');
await page.keyboard.press('F5');
await page.keyboard.up('Control');
```

Puppeteer does support everything we need. Also provide some more code so I can try to fix your code. Your describe is so general.

Comment: This is realy good to know. Thanks. But it doesn't solve my problem. The HTML generated by the CSGOFloat extension does not show up when I try to parse it.

Comment: You can you can wait for them to parse it. Please try to use this.
await page.waitForNavigation();  Or 
await page.waitFor(10000); to wait 10 seconds until page load fully.

Comment: It worked! Now that I know that I need to wait a bit for it to load in, is there any way reduce this time? Such as waiting for something to happen or is setting a value the best way.

Comment: Can you check my answer ? waitForNavigation means wait until page loaded. I don't know is there another wait load for your html. Sorry for it.

Comment: waitForNavigation() just waits until it times out. The only thing that has worked is using page.waitFor(10000). (it works even if I set it to 500 ms which is good)